# WPF blurred opacity mask and a scale layout transform

Tags: wpf

In WPF, I have an image that I am trying to apply a blurred opacity mask with the following code:

```
            var target = new DrawingVisual
            {
                Effect = new BlurEffect
                {
                    Radius = 50
                }
            };

            using (var targetDC = target.RenderOpen())
                targetDC.DrawGeometry(Brushes.White, null, new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(image.RenderSize)));

            image.OpacityMask = new VisualBrush(target)
            {
                Transform = new ScaleTransform(0.75, 0.75, image.RenderSize.Width / 2, image.RenderSize.Height / 2)
            };
```

[which achieves the desired effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWUVT.png)

However, when applying the following `LayoutTransform` to the image:

```
        <Image.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="5" ScaleY="5" CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5" />
        </Image.LayoutTransform>
```

[I get a very different result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WTd2.png)

How can I make it so that the blur effect seems consistent after scaling?

Comment: As a note, the CenterX and CenterY values of a ScaleTransform are given in absolute coordinates, unlike how you typically define the origin of a RenderTransform in relative coordinates. That does however not matter at all, since any coordinate translations are  anyway ignored by the LayoutTransform. In other words, you don't need to set CenterX and CenterY at all.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly goes wrong with your OpacityMask. Something like this should scale as desired:

```
<Image Source="...">
    <Image.OpacityMask>
        <VisualBrush>
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Rectangle Fill="Black" Width="10" Height="10">
                    <Rectangle.Effect>
                        <BlurEffect Radius="1"/>
                    </Rectangle.Effect>
                </Rectangle>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Image.OpacityMask>
    <Image.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="5" ScaleY="5"/>
    </Image.LayoutTransform>
</Image>
```